# returning subarrays with the same dimensions when looping over numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following convenient looping idiom.

```
import numpy

print "shape of"
x = numpy.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']])
print x
print "is", x.shape
for row in x:
    print "shape of", row, "is", row.shape
```

This gives

```
shape of
[['a' 'b']
 ['c' 'd']]
is (2, 2)
shape of ['a' 'b'] is (2,)
shape of ['c' 'd'] is (2,)
```

My question is, can one preserve the convenient `for row in x` idiom while returning arrays which have shape (2,1), in this case? Thanks.
A function which converts the shape of the subarray from (2,) to (2,0) would be fine. E.g.

```
for row in x:
    print "shape of", somefunc(row), "is", row.shape
```

returning

```
shape of ['a' 'b'] is (2,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would want that but you could give this a try:

```
for row in x:
    print "shape of", row, "is", numpy.reshape(row, (1, row.size)).shape
```

In my optinion, a 1d-array is easier to handle. So it does not make much sense to me to reshape it to a "1d-matrix".

Comment: Thanks, but I think you meant to write `(row.size, 1)`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Since `['a' 'b']` is a row vector it should be `(1, number_of_elements)`.

Comment: You're right. BTW, I have a function that requires a 2d array, so I have no choice but to change the dimension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.expand_dim`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to increase the rank of any numpy array:

```
In [7]: x=np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [8]: x.shape
Out[8]: (4,)

In [9]: np.expand_dims(x,axis=-1).shape
Out[9]: (4, 1)
```

Comment: That's a neat solution. How does it compare to `reshape` in generality?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Since neither `expand_dims` nor `reshape` copies the array to a new location in memory, both approaches are really equivalent. So it comes down to a matter of taste which one you prefer.

Comment: @Woltan: Isn't `reshape` more general?

Comment: @FaheemMitha What do you mean with general? Both are valid functions of the `numpy` library. It is a matter of taste, and what sort of parameters you have at hand, which one you want to use. I for myself use `reshape` a lot more often. In your case I would suggest using `expand_dims` since you don`t need to know what the size of the array is...

Comment: @Woltan: By general I mean that one applies more generally than the other. The usual meaning of general. As for using `reshape`, one can always just use `.size` as you do, so I don't see the problem.